# Mocha before function not working correctly

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to read a csv file in my `before` hook but it's getting executed after the test itself for some reason.

```
let csvPath = path.join(__dirname, '/sample-conv.csv')
let messages = []


// read csv and push rows into an array
before(done => {
    fs.createReadStream(csvPath).pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true })).on('data', row => {
        messages.push(row)
    }).on('end', () => {
        console.log('before', messages) // this logs the full array correctly
        done()
    })
})


describe('Should return correct responses', () => {

    let hardCoded = ['Hi', 'This is a response'] // hard codes responses to stub chatbot

    console.log('after', messages) // logs empty array

    it('dummy', done => {  
        expect(true).eq(true);
        done()
    })

    // messages.forEach((row, i) => {
    //     it('Should return expected response for message #' + (i + 1), done => {
    //         const { send, expected } = row
    //         let actual = hardCoded[i]
    //         expect(actual).to.equal(expected)
    //         done()
    //     })
    // })

})
```

There's also the issue that the commented out `it` function is not executed at all. I added the dummy test just to try to fix the `before` issue first. I'm assuming it's not working because of the loop.

Comment: This might be caused by the anti-pattern [described here in the documentation](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises). Could you try without calling `done`?

Comment: Its still not working

Answer (score 2):

`mocha` [RUN CYCLE OVERVIEW](https://mochajs.org/#run-cycle-overview)
:

> 8. When a test file is loaded, Mocha executes all of its suites and finds–but does not execute–any hooks and tests therein.

> 11. Any “before all” hooks (for the root suite, this only happens once; see root hook plugins)

Every call to `describe()` immediately executes its callback. However, calls to `it` record the test for later execution. Mocha is discovering your tests while doing this but not executing them right away. At this point in time, the before hook has not been executed. That's why `console.log('after', messages)` logs empty array.

Simply put, the order of execution is: `describe()` and its callback => `before` hook => `it()`

E.g.

```js
const { expect } = require('chai');

let messages = [];

before((done) => {
  // simulate read csv operator
  setTimeout(() => {
    messages.push(...[1, 2, 3]);
    console.log(`[${new Date().toISOString()}] before`, messages);
    done();
  }, 1000);
});

describe('Should return correct responses', () => {
  console.log(`[${new Date().toISOString()}] after`, messages);

  it('dummy', () => {
    console.log(`[${new Date().toISOString()}] run dummy test case`);
    expect(messages).to.be.deep.eq([1, 2, 3]);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
[2020-12-25T05:31:45.066Z] after []


[2020-12-25T05:31:46.073Z] before [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  Should return correct responses
[2020-12-25T05:31:46.075Z] run dummy test case
    ✓ dummy


  1 passing (1s)
```